# Create classes with special constructor java

Tags: java, constructor

With java you can do :

```
Integer i = 2;
```

Is it possible to make such <s>"constructor "</s> instantiation + initialization for my own classes ?

Comment: That's not a constructor, it's the [boxing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) built into the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a constructor, that is an example of [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). The short answer is *no*. The longer answer is *yes*, if you're willing to write and run a [precompiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiler) (or preprocessor) for your project.

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually a constructor.  What this is doing is assigning the `int` literal 2 to an Integer variable.

Just like assigning the return value of a function to a superclass variable.

i.e.  `Person p = getEmployee(7);`

Answer (score -2):

If I understand what you are saying, you want constructors with default values.
Below is an example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int i;

    public MyClass() {
        this(2);
    }

    public MyClass(Integer i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants to make an object without having to call `new`.

Comment: thats not the question. they want to instantiate a variable by assignment, not a constructor.

Comment: I don't think a downvote is necessary considering the question is unclear.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it seems you were the only one who misunderstood which leads me to believe the question wasn't unclear.